# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, liquibase

I am beginning to learn how to run migration with liquibase in hibernate and spring project. I have added dependency libraries in pom.xml but on adding this to the build properties of my pom.xml i have issues

```
<plugin>
           <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
           <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5</version>
           <configuration>                  
              <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
           </configuration>                
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>process-resources</phase>                                                                  
               <goals>
                 <goal>update</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>

        </plugin>
```

this is the screen shot of the error

[image]

If you hover over it, you get this error

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:update (execution: default, phase: process-resources)
```

Kindly assist me. I am beginning to learn liquibase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using Eclipse? And with it the maven plugin [M2Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) for Eclipse.

If you are interested in details checkout this article about it: 
https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

If you just want to get rid of the error message use one of the quick fix solutions offered by eclipse. I just set it to "Ignore Plugin Goal" and that will add a `<pluginExecutionFilter>` which tell m2eclipse to ignore it.

Comment: I am having this error Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot run Liquibase, liquibase.datasource is not set

Comment: Ask a new question then. One problem = one question. But do not forget to try to solve it yourself and google a little. Then ask a new question if you can't get it to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by using pluginManagement tag, like this:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> ... </plugin>
        <plugin> ... </plugin>
              ....
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```